# Comparing two dates. Class Time inheritance class Dates

Tags: c++, inheritance

Sorry for my bad english, I will try to explain what kind of problem I have.

I am learning C++. I have a task, to compare two dates, after that I should give back result i.e., "how many days are in between these dates".

So there I don't need nothing much, just compare, without using long years or short years. Only was asked that it should be in class and after 30 days it will be next month(rule is that every month has 30 days). And then I should inherit Time class with Date class. So there is similar rule for time class. *After 23:59 there should be 00:00.  And I need one more function `dateAndTime` so that it showed date with time, when time crosses 23:59 , it will be next day or month or even next year.*  I will be thankful for every help, please don't judge me.

So this is my code (I have this in two files .cpp and .h:

**This is my .cpp:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include"date.h"
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main () {


    Dates s1(30,9,1992);
    s1.print();

    Dates s2(29,9,1992);
    s2.print ();

    int dif = dif_days(s1, s2);
    cout << "Between two dates are "<<dif<<" day/s" <<endl;

    Time T1(23,58);
    T1.print();

    Time T2;                         //So this code after 23:59 will give me back 00:00, 
    if (T1.minutes == 59){           //I wonder how I can put his code under timeUpdate function
    if (T1.hours == 23) {
        T2.hours = 0;
    } else {
        T2.hours = T1.hours +1;
        }
        T2.minutes = 0;
    } else {
        T2.hours = T1.hours;
        T2.minutes = T1.minutes+1;
    }
    cout <<"New Time: " <<setw(2) << setfill('0')<<T2.hours <<":"<<setw(2) << setfill('0')<<T2.minutes<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

**And this one is my second file date.hh:**

```
using namespace std;

class Dates {
public:
int day;
int month;
int year;

public:
    //Constructors
    Dates();
    Dates(int, int, int);
    //Destructor
    ~Dates();
    //void do not return values
    void setDay(int);
    void setMonth(int);
    void setYear(int);

    int getDay();
    int getMonth();
    int getYear();

    void print();
};

Dates::Dates(){
    day = 0;
    month = 0;
    year = 0;
}
Dates::~Dates(){
    day = 0;
    month = 0;
    year = 0;
}

Dates::Dates(int d, int m, int y){
    setDay(d);
    setMonth(m);
    setYear(y);
}

void Dates::print (){
    cout <<"Date: "<<day<<"/"<< month<<"/"<< year <<endl;

}

void Dates::setDay(int d){
    day = d;
}
void Dates::setMonth(int m){
    month = m;
}
void Dates::setYear(int y){
    year = y;
}

int Dates::getDay(){
    return day;
}
int Dates::getMonth(){
    return month;
}
int Dates::getYear(){
    return year;
}


int dif_days(Dates, Dates);       //Function to compare and return day count

int dif_days( Dates s1, Dates s2){
    int D1_d = 365*s1.getYear() + 30*s1.getMonth() + s1.getDay();
    int D2_d = 365*s2.getYear() + 30*s2.getMonth() + s2.getDay();
  return D1_d-D2_d;
}

class Time {
public:
int hours, minutes;

public:
 //Constructors
    Time();
    Time(int, int);
    //Destructor
    ~Time();
    //void do not return values
    void setHours(int);
    void setMinutes(int);

    int getHours();
    int getMinutes();

   void print();
};
Time::Time(){
    hours = 0;
    minutes = 0;
}
Time::~Time(){
    hours = 0;
    minutes = 0;
}

Time::Time(int h, int mi){
    setHours(h);
    setMinutes(mi);
}
void Time::print (){
    cout <<"Time: "<<hours<<":"<< minutes<<endl;
}

void Time::setHours(int h){
    hours = h;
}
void Time::setMinutes(int mi){
    minutes = mi;
}
int Time::getHours(){
    return hours;
}
int Time::getMinutes(){
    return minutes;
}
                             //In here I tried to put fi statement in function so that I could call it from main file.
//int timeUpdate(Time, Time);
//int timeUpdate(Time T1, Time T2){
//if (T1.minutes == 59){
//    if (T1.hours == 23) {
//        T2.hours = 0;
//    } else {
//        T2.hours = T1.hours +1;
//        }
//        T2.minutes = 0;
//    } else {
//        T2.hours = T1.hours;
//        T2.minutes = T1.minutes+1;
//    }
//    return 0;
//}
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: So the problem basicly is writen in the third paragraph, there is what should need to get out of this code. I have only some thing , what should I get , dont know how to get that script from .cpp file , where is written comment , that I want to put it in function and if it is possible to put onder name updateTime and put on second file .h . As well I need to inheritate class Time with class Dates, I just dont understand how, we tdont have much programming books in our native language.